# Do I need to calculate the field or update on each transaction?

Tags: postgresql, design-patterns

Trying to design database. I have `User` table, which supposed to have `balance` field. It can be calculated each time I need balance based on 4 tables like below:

[image]

So I need to do some math like sum of all deposits, minus sum of withdrawals, minus bet amount+profit, plus amount from bonuses. There can be thousands of records for each user in each related table.

Or alternatively I can just update `balance` field from the application code whenever one of the related table has been altered.

However, first method is tend to be slower and slower as database grows. Second method is prone to errors, in case my application will fail to update the field and real balance will get asynced with balance field.

I wonder if there is any design pattern or technique to handle this cases? How the online bankings or similar services are counting balance? Are they going through each bank transaction every time balance is requested?

Comment: *in case my application will fail to update the field*: that would be a bug. By that logic, the first method is also prone to error in case you forget to include a withdrawal or a bonus. Test your code. Make all the updates to one of those tables go through as few methods as possible and make sure thos methods do the correct thing, by testing them. Use locking (optimistic or pessimistic) to avoid bugs cause by race conditions between concurrent threads.

Answer (score 0):

For the first method , in order to prevent from loading all transaction to calculate the account balance , we can make a snapshot value of the account balance periodically (e.g. at the end of day/month or for certain number of completed transactions) such that when calculating the latest account balance , we only need to load latest snapshot account balance and only the transaction after that latest snapshot time rather than loading all transaction records.

You can also found the similar snapshot pattern in the [event-sourcing](/questions/tagged/event-sourcing)

Comment: Basically have dedicated table with countAmountFromId and amountSum fields for each related table, then update this table periodically. For balance use combination of amount from that table and loading-counting from each related table, but with less amount of data.